# Mention of Tamil and other languages in ancient sanskrit Hindu texts

Tags: puranas, tamil

Most of the ancient Hindu literature including the puranas were first written down in Sanskrit. But is there any mention of other languages like Tamil in the Puranas..? Does Skandha Purana mention Tamil in reference to ancient Chola King conferring the title of 'Murugan' on Karthikeyan?

Comment: The concept of an culture called Tamil is a recent development that was originally fostered upon India by the British. There is an excellent book on this that details and numerous references. "Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines" by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan  You can read about it here - http://www.breakingindia.com/

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Aryan/Dravidian divide is a disproven myth, but Tamil is a language that is as ancient as Sanskrit, if not more. Culturally, there was very little difference between North and South. The question here is about the language only.

Comment: There are references to Prakrits in the Puranas, if that helps.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan On a related note, I think it will be a good idea to start new stackexchange forums on Sanskrit and Tamil languages. I think it requires a lot of SE points to start a forum. Would you be willing to consider the idea? I can rope in some sanskrit and Tamil experts. Thanks!

Comment: @Naveen Well, there is a Tamil site proposal here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95558/tamil-language I think there was an Indian languages proposal before, which would have been better, but I guess it must have failed.  In any case, I don't think you need any reputation points to start a proposal.

Comment: How does the proposal pass or fail? Is it voted upon?

Comment: Ok. 57 more followers and 40 questions with score of 10 or more. Pretty demanding, but can be worked out.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan And then it moves to commitment and then beta. Do share with your friend in SE. Hope it comes to fruition soon. We are shooting for Tamil and Sanskrit initially.

Comment: @Naveen I doubt it would come to fruition.  I think a broader Indian Languages site would stand a better chance of gathering enough followers compared to a site exclusively devoted to Tamil.